# Script to change ImportHTML value in google sheets

Tags: javascript, scripting, google-sheets

I am using the following very simple script to change the value of a cell in google sheets. While it does change the value of the correct sell, it doesn't render the results as though it would if I clicked on the cell and manually input the ImportHtml command.  Any ideas?

```
function myFunction() 
    {
      var blankSyntax ='ImportHtml("http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyOfficers?symbol=V", "table", 1)'
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(blankSyntax);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change setValue to setFormula

```
function myFunction() 
    {
      var blankSyntax   ='ImportHtml("http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyOfficers?symbol=V", "table", 1)'
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setFormula(blankSyntax);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to add to the answer, not edit the question.